# React | How to Dynamically Render Limited Numbers of a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, for-loop, enumeration

I am making a rating component that has 5 stars. Each star will have different symbol according to the value.

```
<span>
        <i
          className={
            value >= 1
              ? 'fas fa-star'
              : value >= 0.5
              ? 'fas fa-star-half-alt'
              : 'far fa-star'
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
```

Instead of copy pasting 5 of these and changing values, I wanted to know how can I make it dynamic.
Map() didn't make sense to use since I am not enumerating through imported data and stars have a fixed limit of 5.

Idea: Multiplying index with '1' and adding index to '0.5'.

FULL CODE:

```
import React from 'react';

const Rating = ({ value, text }) => {
  return (
      <span key={index}>
        <i
          className={
            value >= 1
              ? 'fas fa-star'
              : value >= 0.5
              ? 'fas fa-star-half-alt'
              : 'far fa-star'
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
    )
})
}



export default Rating;

//full star = fas fa-star

//empty star = far fa-star

//half-star = fas fa-star-half-alt
```

Comment: Just realized my idea doesn't actually work. If it starts from 0 then 1 * 0 = 0 and 0.5 + 0 = 0.5, doesn't work. If it starts from 1 then 1 * 1 = 1 and 0.5 + 1 = 1.5, doesn't work either. So 0.5 have to be -0.5 and the enumeration should start from 1.

Comment: Just run a loop from `1` to `floor(star)` and check if there's a 0.5 is remaining after the loop for the last half star i.e, `star-floor(star)>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```js
const Ratings = ({value}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        [...Array(5)].map((ignore,ind) => { // you just use indice here
          return (
            <span key={ind}>
              <I
                className={
                  value >= ind + 1
                  ? 'fas fa-star'
                  : value >= ind + 0.5
                  ? 'fas fa-star-half-alt'
                  : 'far fa-star'
                } 
              ></i>
            </span>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
export default Ratings
```

Comment: I got ''Error: Rating(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.''. It is probably because I am using a stateless component. Do you know how can I change your map function to work in stateless, since it seems a bit hacky to me.

Comment: ```import React from 'react';

const Rating = ({ value, text }) => {
    [...Array(5)].map((ignore, index) => {
  return (
      <span key={index}>
        <i
          className={
            value >= 1
              ? 'fas fa-star'
              : value >= 0.5
              ? 'fas fa-star-half-alt'
              : 'far fa-star'
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
    )
})
}



export default Rating;

//full star = fas fa-star

//empty star = far fa-star

//half-star = fas fa-star-half-alt
```

Comment: I edited the answer to work from direct pasting

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` is still not a bad idea. you can use the following code. And assume that a variable `rating` has the current value. e.g `rating = 2.5`.

```
var arr = new Array(5);
var list = arr.map((value, index)=>{
   return (
      <span key={index}>
        <i className={rating<=0.5+index ? 'fas fa-star-half-alt' : rating <= 1+index ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'}></i>
      </span>
   );
})
```

Then you can use the `list` variable to place your rating.